# what is this seed?

Tags: food-identification

It looks like lentils but is yellow. Same size.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like yellow split peas: ["Split Pea" - *Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_pea).

Also called *lappeh* in Persian, *matar* in Hindi.

They are in the same family as lentils and can be prepared similarly.